# How do I run a windows executable in linux shell script?

Tags: shell-script, windows, executable

I have an executable program (no source code, just the compiled executable) that was made in windows (.exe extension).  It doesn't use any graphics... it simply reads and writes files.  I want to be able to run it in a linux shell script so that I don't have to switch operating systems to get my output.  Is there a way to use or convert the executable for linux operating systems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wine works even for Windows CLI apps.

Comment: Is there a way to run it without Wine?

Comment: Yes. Run Windows.

Comment: Obviously... But i'm looking for a way without wine or windows.

Comment: Rebuild from source.

Comment: As I said... no source available...

Comment: Write your own clone of Wine.

Comment: @Paul There is no way to run an executable built for a foreign OS without some kind of adaptation layer. That's what wine is. You must use wine. That's what it's for.

Comment: @Paul: Perhaps if we knew *why* you don't want to use Wine we could make a few suggestions.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: The reason why not: No superuser privileges.

Comment: You... have no superuser privileges... but you can switch operating systems?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yes, i have an account on both systems, but no privileges to install software one either system... it's just cumbersome to execute in one, then switch to the other to complete my task...  I just wanted to know if there was a way around it... apparently not, but thanks anyways :)

Comment: You can't ask the sysadmin to install Wine?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run Windows binaries (source compiled to run in Windows) on Linux without going through a Windows emulator of some sort.

So if you don't want to run Windows in a virtual machine, or you don't want to run Wine or anything similar, sorry, but it won't run on Linux.

Comment: I don't really need most of the features of a virtual windows environment (i.e. graphics, etc)... is there a way to get an emulator just for the windows DOS command prompt? That is really all that I'll need to run the program.

Comment: Yes. It's called Wine.

Comment: @Paul If what you have is truly a DOS program then [dosemu](http://www.dosemu.org/) might work. But that's probably not what you have.

Answer (score 2):

Beside *wine*, as already suggested, a virtual machine like *VMware-Player* is fine to execute Windows programs, without rebooting.

Jar-files and some mono-applications will not need Wine or a Windows, running in a VM, but we wouldn't call that Windows executable.

A windows-executable, which runs in the shell, is most of the time still a windows executable, and won't run on DOS. Don't let the user interface fool you! They will report 'This program will not run in DOS-mode' or similar.

Comment: Regarding running CLI win32 executables, from a real Free-DOS/MS-DOS, it can be done, although some limitations do apply.  Specifically check out HXDOS http://www.japheth.de/HX.html, it also includes a utility named PatchPE, which will convert binaries from Win32-PE to DOS-PE.